# Facebook SDK - Wrong ID while invating friends

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I want to send invites to user's facebook friends. For that I use the following code:

```
String KEY_MESSAGE = "message";

    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString(KEY_MESSAGE, "Learn how to make your Android apps social");

    WebDialog requestsDialog = (new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(context, Session.getActiveSession(), params))
            .setOnCompleteListener(new WebDialog.OnCompleteListener() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values, FacebookException error) {
                    if (error == null) {

                        Log.w(TAG, "Posted successfully. Values: " + values);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Post canceled");
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Strange error: " + error);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            })
            .build();
    requestsDialog.show();
```

My app shows request dialog. I select one friend and push "Send" button. Then I find out this friend id via [this](http://findmyfacebookid.com) website. My logs:

```
Posted successfully. Values: Bundle[{to[0]=<unknown-friend-id>, request=388113714696190}]
```

Friend that I want to bу invited do not recive any invites. And his id do not equals "unknown-friend-id". Why can it be wrong? I've got no ideas

**P.S.** "unknow-friend-id" is set of numbers. It is someones id. I decided not to publish it. And don't look throw the comments. They are for priveous version of the question.

Comment: Are you sure the invite hadn't been sent? Everything seems to be fine. The bundle contains id of the request, not the post. See [this documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/send-requests)

Comment: That is the correct user id. You get an app scoped user id and not their global user id back

Comment: @WizKid Whatever my friend didn't  recive any invites.

Comment: Do you have a canvas version of your app? You should read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @WizKid. As he said:

It doesn't work because your app hasn't a canvas version. For more information you should read [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app)